# Nested loop not starting at 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a nested for loop for when someone enters the race.  The problem i'm having is that if a user selects a date that is not on the dates held I am pushing them to the next 'official' date.  I have a list of dates in a csv file and i'm reading it well.  My problem is my nested loop keeps incrementing its starting point in the csv file.

```
import csv, time
from datetime import date, timedelta

class RunDates():

    def __init__(self):
        self.enterDate = '4/12/14'
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(open('dates.csv', 'rb'))

    def findRunDate(self):

        # Get the row of entered date or next closest
        csvlist = enumerate(self.reader)
        for i in range(5):
            t = time.strptime(self.enterDate, '%m/%d/%y')
            newdateArr = (date(t.tm_year, t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday)+timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m/%d/%y').split('/')
            newdateStr = '/'.join( [str(int(newdateArr[0])), str(int(newdateArr[1])), newdateArr[2]] )
            print newdateStr, i

            for num, row in csvlist:
                print row['Date'], num
                break
                if newdateStr == row['Date']:
                    print 'Row Number: ' + str(num)
                    print 'Row Date: ' + row['Date']
                    print 'new Date: ' + newdateStr
                    break
                else:
                    pass



#Testing
a = RunDates()
a.findRunDate()
```

The break is in the second loop just to test where the loop is starting.  Whenever I run this code I get the following:

```
4/12/14 0
4/29/16 0
4/13/14 1
4/28/16 1
4/14/14 2
4/27/16 2
4/15/14 3
4/26/16 3
4/16/14 4
4/25/16 4
```

So the first loop comes up with 5 dates and correctly formats them fine.  But the second one keeps increasing the rows it starts at and i'm not sure why?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Are you expecting `num` to start at 0 each time you enter the `for` loop? Do you want the csv enumeration to restart each time?

Comment: I want num to start at 0 each time, that way if someone would join recently the first few dates wouldn't be skipped over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv` variable is masking the `csv` module. This is a future bug waiting to happen.

That said, the `csv` variable is also a wrapper around a file reader. You don't reset that, so it's going to just pull in higher and higher lines.

If you want to restart the iterator at the beginning of the file, you should probably just read in all the data to a list.

Comment: Yes calling it csv was a mistake, that aside do you think it would be a good idea to read the whole file if its 1000 lines long when I really only need 1 or 2  lines? Genuinely curious

Comment: Actually maybe that's a good way to do it, a dictionary would probably be better though if I need more than one column right?

Comment: You could just as easily initialize the reader inside the first loop, scan through, and then close the file and reader. Then do it again for each time through the loop. I'd say it was a matter of preference. Several thousand lines isn't much memory, and if you drop the references after you have what you want, the garbage collector will take care of it for you.

Comment: You are right, that's what I decided to do.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you intialize csv with enumerator at the beginning of the outer loop.  So it just keeps pulling next values from the reader.

If you want to start over every time you enter the inner loop,  either read all the values into the list first as Austing suggested or create new reader and enumerator right before the inner loop